# How to display 2 categories in the index.php page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display a simple front page with 2 categories,

But when I enter 2 same code, the result is empty,

But one code, the result appears

*I look like:*

**Title: chicken category**

Content

**Title: cow category**

Content

I tried with a simple php code:

```js
<h2 class="home1">10 Best Chicken</h2> 
<div class="1"><?php query_posts('cat=9' . '&showposts=3'.'&paged='.$paged); ?></div>

<h2 class="home1">10 Best Cow</h2> 
<div class="1"><?php query_posts('cat=10' . '&showposts=3'.'&paged='.$paged); ?></div>
```

How the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `query_posts` , use `WP_Query` instead

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if((is_home())&& ($paged < 1)) { ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'home-featured' ); ?>
<?php } ?>
<div class="wisata-konten">   
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">       
<div class="col-md-12">
<?php if((is_home())&& ($paged > 1)) { ?>
<h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { echo 'Halaman '. get_query_var('paged'); } ?></h1>
<?php } ?>

<div class="row"><div class="boxer2">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>
<div class="col-md-4"><?php get_template_part( 'thumb' ); ?></div>
<?php endwhile; ?></div></div>

<?php fastestwp_pagenavi(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<h2>Not Found</h2>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.
<?php endif; ?>
<h2 class="home1">Lombok Open Trip</h2> 
<?php $args = array( 'cat' => 9 , 'posts_per_page' => 3 , 'paged' => $paged );


$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
?><h2 class="home1">Lombok Promo</h2><?php
$args2 = array( 'cat' => 10 , 'posts_per_page' => 3 , 'paged' => $paged );

$the_query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query2->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
} ?>
<div class="wisata-testimoni">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">                     
<div id="testimoni" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<?php fastestwp_comments(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="tombol"><a class= "medium beli blue pull-right" href="<?php echo home_url() ; ?>/testimoni" >Lihat Semua Testimoni <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do I apply this code?
Whether in function.php or directly paste in index.php

Comment: You can do that via 2 ways , 1st - directly put it inside index.php
2nd - write a shortcode for this in functions.php and call the shortcode inside index.php

Comment: Where should I put the code? Please see my full index.php code in the comments

Comment: I have updated the code , check it and also please delete your code from answer :)

Comment: Glad to help you :)